# Unable to access web service from android

Tags: java, android, web-services, soap, wsdl

My server is running in Tomcat. Here is my WSDL path:

```
http://10.99.60.52:8082/rjWebServices/wsdl/UserAuthenticationService.wsdl
```

`SOAP` address location in `WSDL`:

```
<soap:address location="http://localhost:8082/rjWebServices/services/UserAuthenticationService" />
```

When trying to access the service from `SOAP UI`, I'm getting proper response.

But when trying to create a new `SoapObject` in android, I'm getting `InvocationTargetException`.

Here is my `Android` Code:

```
String SOAP_ACTION = "http://10.99.60.52:8082/rjWebServices/services/UserAuthenticationService";
String METHOD_NAME = "PasswordValidation";
String NAMESPACE = "http://10.99.60.52:8082/rjWebServices/services/UserAuthenticationService/";
String URL = "com.retailJava.webServices.services.UserAuthenticationService";
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

My `IP` is: `10.99.60.52`

Answer (score 0):

10.0.2.2:8082 would be the solution if you are trying to run your app on the emulator on the same machine where tomcat is installed!

If you are running the app on the device make sure that your device is on the same network or you have the route to your server from your device's network.

10.x.x.x is a private network and isnt valid on the internet. Download  terminal emulator app and see of you can ping your server!

Answer (score 0):

```
String SOAP_ACTION = "http://10.99.60.52:8082/rjWebServices/services/UserAuthenticationService";
```

I don't think, this is your soap action.
Search operation "PasswordValidation" in your wsdl, under bindings , you can find correct soap action.

```
String URL = "com.retailJava.webServices.services.UserAuthenticationService";
```

I think here you should provide your end point url.
Can you paste rest of your code where you are calling the webservice url.

InovcationTargetException means that the method that you invoked threw an exception. To figure out what the problem is with your method itself, wrap the invoke method call around a try-catch block and log

```
invocationTargetException.getTargetException().
```

Answer (score 0):

use that code

```
String SOAP_ACTION = "http://10.99.60.52/rjWebServices/services/UserAuthenticationService";
```

10.99.60.52 is your ip address..